# How NIC and ring buffers work?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I want know how network interface card and ring buffers work?I think ring buffers can be mapped into memory..RX ring and TX ring... then,how it works with input and output signals and registers?Please explain architecture of NIC card ?

Comment: The typical NIC receives (and transmits) Ethernet frames to (from) memory buffers listed in a ring structure (or linked list).  The device driver (SW) typically allocates these buffers for the NIC hardware to use when the NIC & driver are initialized.  Refer to a datasheet of an Ethernet MAC for specific details.

Comment: please explain more...

Comment: Each Ethernet MAC has its own way of implementing its ring buffers (or linked list).  Again, refer to the datasheet of the specific EMAC you are using.  For more vagueness, read *"The simple NIC"* section in [Turtles on the wire: understanding how the OS uses the modern NIC](https://www.joyent.com/blog/virtualizing-nics)

Answer (score 0):

See partial explanation in next answers:

1. https://serverfault.com/a/1078591/537333
2. https://ultramessaging.github.io/currdoc/doc/Design/packetloss.html#lossnicringbuffer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).